# Android Custom User agent not working with ADAL plugin

Tags: android, azure, user-agent, adal

I am developing a hybrid mobile app, where my company users will login with there active directory credentials using Azure

My company ADFS authenticates only if request has specific user agent, I am appending custom user agent in config file, this is working fine in IOS

but in Android my custom user Agent string is replacing with "PkeyAuth/1.0"

Please help me

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Did you find a solution to this problem Shilpa?

Comment: no, I have added complete ADAL library in the project and updated source files by appending my custom user agent string with "PkeyAuth/1.0" this is a work around not actual solution